# How to wait for subscribtion Iron Router with auto-publish?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm actually developping a WebApp with Meteor. Since i'm more focused on UI and specs than being ready for production and look at security issues.(would do that later, after I've done a good PoC).

I would like to keep the autopublish and insecure packages (damn that's cool to go quick).

I'm bumping into an annoying issue with Iron Router.
The problem is pretty simple, but I'cannot find a way to make it work properly. Sometime data return randomly undefined.

```
Router.route('/stuff/:_id', {
  name: 'stuff',
  template: 'stuff',

  data: function(){
    var stuff = Stuffs.findOne(this.params._id);
    console.log("stuff: ", stuff);
    return {headerTitle: stuff.name, stuffData: stuff};
  },
  action: function(){
    this.render();
  }
});
```

It's actually not that random, I guess something like this happen:

Working well when I hit this route from link from the App (I guess the data is ready)

But on page refresh, or on naviguate by the url, I could have this annoying undefined.

Everything is autopublish, so it's would be strange to use a waitOn into my route...

Does someone hit the same problem and got a solution?

Comment: What would be undefined?

Comment: The data, here "stuff"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get it!
Was simpler than I expected!

Related this issue:
https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/295

Obviously Meteor cursor are reactive, finally I just have to do:

```
Router.route('/stuff/:_id', {
  name: 'stuff',
  template: 'stuff',

  data: function(){
    var stuff = Stuffs.findOne(this.params._id);
    if(stuff){
        console.log("stuff: ", stuff);
        return {headerTitle: stuff.name, stuffData: stuff};
    }
  },
  action: function(){
    this.render();
  }
});
```

Testing if stuff is undefined before doing anything, so stuff is not used -> no errors. On update the hook will be rerun, done.

That's it. Pretty cool and simple, I don't even think about that!

Comment: Yes, I had tried to do something similar. And I have no idea if there's a better way. Have to check out Flow-Router in this regard.

Comment: Solution coming from the iron router creator Tom Coleman, I think it at least not to bad ;) I'm thinking about Flow Router too, I've to look hover it

Answer (score 1):

> Working well when I hit this route from link from the App (I guess the data is ready)

Data is already present on the client-side. In this case, Iron Router is doing client-side routing only (ie, no calls going to server).

> But on page refresh, or on naviguate by the url, I could have this annoying undefined.

In this case you are actually requesting data from the server-side..via a HTTP GET request, for which you probably don't have any routes defined.

**EDIT**

I was wrong regarding the HTTP GET request. It seems that no matter which link we load from browser, Meteor server sends the whole build. After the whole build is loaded onto the client-side, Iron Router decides which template to load based on the URL path.

---

It seems on page load/refresh, the page gets rendered before receiving data from server-side. This is the most probable reason for getting `undefined`.

Attached this listener on the client-side database to check when it is updated by server:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Stuffs.find().observe({
    added: function(doc) {
        console.log("Updated Stuffs : ", JSON.stringify(doc));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Why? Everything [here stuff] is autopublish/autosuscribe. So the data would be avaible on the mini mongo db, which should allow Stuffs.findOne(this.params._id) to work. Sometime it's working on refresh, sometime not. (I thinks it's would be possible, just imagine not, how would they implement a watch auto refresh on code change?)

Comment: I tried to reproduce your code and got the same error. It seems that on refreshing the page, it is rendered before server response is received. Hence, the `undefined`. However, as soon as client-side receives the data from server, the page gets automatically updated.

Comment: Thanks I will test that! I'm actually pretty disapointed by this issue. It's like giving perfect tools to mockup/PoC with this autopublish/suscribe package, but finally have to hack it to make it work properly. I mean I expect something which would work on any case simply until you decide to do your own system, where I will have to remove this code from each of my query! To me it's not even updating the page when the data is avaible on client (using Mongol tools to observe the data)

Comment: Found the way, I upvote you anyway for your help! thanks